# How can I get ng-list behavior, but with a slightly different model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-nglist

For ng-list, you'd normally have a simple array for your model:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Instead, I have an array of objects like such:

```
[{ id: 1, value: 2 }, { id: 2, value: 3 } ... ]
```

Is there any way for me to be able to output each `value` in a text input similar to this?:

```
2, 3
```

Seemingly ng-list is what I want, but obviously my model is wrong. Will I just have to translate my model or is there a way to do this with what I have?

Thanks!

Comment: `yourObj.map(function(x){ return x.value; })` or `_.pluck(yourObj,"value")` in underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Benjamin Gruenbaum comment which i think is the simplest solution:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="test">
```

and in your controller

```
 $scope.test = [{ id: 1, value: 2 }, { id: 2, value: 3 } ].map(function(x){ return x.value; });
```

Comment: it will make 2 way binding with the scope var not the actual object you're using but you could also have object changes affect the test var if that's what you need, easily

Comment: So just setup a $watch on the original array, updating the map for $scope.test on change?

Comment: Either that or - i would prefer - have your data in a service to use in multiple controllers and $broadcast on change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ng-list, but according to docs `Text input that converts between a delimited string and an array of strings`, so it is for strings, I think the best you can do is watch your array for changes then add the property you want to a new array for example

```
$scope.myObjects = [{id:1, name:'john'},{id:2, name: 'charles'}];
$scope.myStringArray = [];

$scope.$watch('myObjects', function(){
    var newArray=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myObejcts.lenght; i++) {
       newArray.push($scope.myObjects[i].name)//in case you want to list names
    }
    $scope.myStringArray = newArray;
} , true);
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Then just do an ng-list with $scope.myStringArray?

Comment: yes my StringArray should look like ['john', 'charles'], if you use the id property it will be [1,2]